# What is the significance of the sign of the velocity for a particle executing SHM?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, velocity

So while deriving equation for the velocity of particle executing SHM at any point, I noticed a difference in the result depending on what wave (sine or cosine) you chose.

> For $x=A\cos\omega t$:
> $\quad \ \,v=-\omega\sqrt{A^2-x^2}$
> For $x=A\sin\omega t$:
> $\quad \ \,v=\omega\sqrt{A^2-x^2}$

Can anyone explain to me why the difference is there and what it means, since both equation are basically the same with only a phase difference?

Comment: Have you tried putting x=0 and observing that the direction of velocity indicates to a phase difference of $\pi/2$?

Answer (score 2):

It is just related to two different initial conditions for the system.

Assume the system is a mass attached to a spring.

If $$x=A\cos(\omega t)$$ then this represents holding the mass with the spring extended in the +x direction at t=0.  When you let go, the velocity is in the negative x direction.

This agrees with the calculated velocity you get by taking the derivative of the above expression:  $$v=-\omega A\sin(\omega t)$$

The second expression represents the mass passing through x = 0 at t=0 and moving in the +x direction (as time increases, x grows positive), which is what the calculated velocity tells you also:  $$v=\omega A\cos(\omega t)$$

Comment: "This agrees with the calculated velocity you get" - unfortunately it does not - look carefully at the expressions the OP has asked about. These expressions *should* be the same, no matter what the initial phase of the oscillation is as the expressions give velocity as a function of displacement, not as a function of time.

Comment: Just poorly worded on my part.  I should have instead written "one gets" since the "you" in "you get" was not referring to the OP, but a general "you" who takes the derivative of the first expression I wrote in my post.

Comment: In that case negative sign should cancel depending on the time, which doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those expressions are right.  If $x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)$, then $v(t) = -A\omega \sin(\omega t)$.  You wrote

$$v(t) = -\omega \sqrt{A^2-x^2}=-A\omega \big|\sin(\omega t)\big|$$

If we write $x(t) = A\cos(\omega t - \delta)$, then your two examples correspond to $\delta = 0$ and $\delta = \pi/2$.  In the general case,

$$v(t) = -A\omega \sin(\omega t- \delta)= A\omega \cos(\omega t - \delta -\pi/2)$$
so we see that in general, the velocity function is related to the position function by a $\pi/2$ phase shift and scaling by $\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions are for speed and not velocity, so the sign is irrelevant.

The reason this is the case is because during the derivation, there will be a step like:

$$v = w\cos(wt) = w\sqrt{\cos^2(wt)}$$

As soon as you write $\cos\theta$ as $\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}$, you instantly lose its sign - this is the definition of the "modulus" function.

Therefore your expressions are equivalent.